# Mismatch in custom object field count in rest api and salesforce UI

Tags: community, custom-object, rest, java

I have a java codebase for performing CRUD on salesforce as an rdbms db. I was looking at the response on my rest api and that on SF setup UI of a custom object that I create in object manager. I have not performed any operation on the custom object. I am seeing a mismatch in column count returned; on SF UI, there not every column is listed where as in the rest response, other columns are returned as well. My question is, why can I not see every column of the table on SF UI?

SF UI custom object fields under "Fields and Relationships" as Field Name:

```
[
"CreatedById" ,
"LastModifiedById",
"OwnerId",
"Name"
]
```

Fields returned in rest api:

```
[
"Id",
"OwnerId",
"IsDeleted",
"Name",
"CreatedDate",
"CreatedById",
"LastModifiedDate",
"LastModifiedById",
"SystemModstamp"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the System fields present on every object in Salesforce. Not all of them may be explicitly visible on the UI sometimes, but you should always assume that it is somewhere there in  the background. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/system_fields.htm#:%7E:text=The%20following%20fields%20are%20read,a%20user%20modifies%20a%20record.).

```
Id
IsDeleted
CreatedById
CreatedDate
LastModifiedById
LastModifiedDate
SystemModstamp
```

Comment: That is pretty bad design to hide columns just like that. Is there any toggle or any configuration which I can unset to get them to show up on SF UI. Any documentation as to why these are invisible?

Comment: I don't see there is any way to toggle that up in the UI. I updated my answer with the link.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it clarifies a lot.